# Inserting an entry to its table using the auto incremented ID as part of the value

Tags: mysql, insert-into

Is it possible to use only one query to insert an entry to a table with one of its columns needs to use the entry's ID

example table schema:

```
tbl_post:
 col_id: (auto-increment)
 title: string
 body: string
 guid: string
```

example query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_post(title, body, guid)
VALUES("sample title", "sample body", CONCAT("http://site/?id=", col_id))
```

result of query:

```
col_id | title        | body        | guid
-------+--------------+-------------+--------------
1      | sample title | sample body | http://site/?id=1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the next auto-increment id in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761403/how-to-get-the-next-auto-increment-id-in-mysql)

Comment: Question is not clear .

Comment: I want a query that will result to my 'result of query'

Comment: you can create a stored procedure, best ya got. One call all in one swoop. Otherwise depending on your programming interface, you can make a subsequent call to get the id just inserted. (you certainly don't need the other data, as you just gave it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible; you can't use auto increment value for populating other columns in single `INSERT`.

In general best option is to run a single transaction that performs the `INSERT` followed by `UPDATE`:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO tbl_post(title, body)
VALUES("sample title", "sample body");

UPDATE tbl_post SET guid=CONCAT("http://site/?id=", col_id) 
 WHERE col_id=LAST_INSERT_ID();

COMMIT;
```

This is guaranteed to be atomic on InnoDB table so it either succeeds or fails completely. You are out of luck with MyISAM as it doesn't support transactions.

As @Drew pointed out in comments, you may roll this into a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insupd (ttitle VARCHAR(32), tbody VARCHAR(16))
BEGIN
 START TRANSACTION;
 INSERT INTO tbl_post(title, body)
  VALUES(ttitle, tbody);

 UPDATE tbl_post SET guid=CONCAT("http://site/?id=", col_id) 
  WHERE col_id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
 COMMIT;
END;
```

Once that's done, you simply use the following to insert data:

```
CALL insupd('yourfancytitle','blah.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Max Id + 1.

Maybe this topic will help you out.

[php mysql insert (max(id)+1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620998/php-mysql-insert-maxid1)